# Uploading an image with multer / react-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, express, multer, react-dropzone

I cannot seem to upload an image to my uploads folder using express,multer and react-dropzone. My code is as follows:

```
<Dropzone
    style={{position: "relative"}}
    accept="image/*, video/*"
    onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
    onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter.bind(this)}
    onDragLeave={this.onDragLeave.bind(this)}
    name='avatar'
  >
    { dropzoneActive && <div style={overlayStyle}>Drop files...</div> }
    <div>

      <h2>Dropped files</h2>
      {

          files.map(f => <div><li>{f.name} - {f.size} bytes</li> 
          <img style={{height:'100px'}}src={f.preview}/></div>)
      }
    </div>
  </Dropzone>
```

A basic file upload using the dropzone example. Then my submit function is:

```
createBlog(){

var file = this.state.files[0];
var file_name = file.name;
//api/blog
fetch('http://localhost:8080/saveBlog', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  "Accept": 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  //"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  file: file,
  file_name: file_name
})
  }).then((response) =>  {
  ...
  }))
  }, function(error) {
   console.log('error: ',error.message)
  })
}
```

**Note** that **file** returns all the properties that image has, E.G. lastModifiedDate, name, preview, size, type, webkitRelativePath.

However, when I pass the data to the server the response I get is :

```
{ file:
 { preview: 'blob:http://localhost:3000/954e0002-3045-44c4-bcd8-70dc26d0d416' 
},
file_name: 'image.jpg' } 'Body'
undefined 'files'
```

Where my server code involving the image is :

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' });
...
...
router.post('/saveBlog', upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body, 'Body');
    console.log(req.file, 'files');
    res.end();
});
```

I am hoping someone can help tell me why my images are not going to my uploads folder as I have spent a long time trying to figure out this basic example.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you're trying using `JSON.stringify()` for your request payload and Multer expects and only works with formData. You also need to remove the headers you have or use `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`

You have:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  file: file,
  file_name: file_name
})
```

You need to use formData() instead:

```
createBlog(){

    const file = this.state.files[0];
    const file_name = file.name;
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    data.append('file_name', file_name);

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/saveBlog', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: data
         }).then((response) =>  {
            ...
         }))
         }, function(error) {
          console.log('error: ',error.message)
    })
}
```